# Straight forward derivation of the bch formula?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Im doing a project on rigid body dynamics and need to derive the bch formula, anyone know a simple yet complete derivation?

Comment: Try this to start with (for Lie matrix groups, at least) http://www.math.ucla.edu/~vsv/liegroups2007/7.pdf